# Vaadin Spring and Hibernate: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, hibernate, vaadin

The Model:

```java
    @Entity
    ...
    public class ScolProgressionPopulation {    
       ...        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "population")
        private List<ScolProgressionSemestre> progressions;        
       ...
    }
```

The repo:

```java
    public interface ScolProgressionPopulationRepository extends JpaRepository<ScolProgressionPopulation, Long>
```

The View:

```java
    @Route(value = "progression", layout = ApplicationLayout.class)
    @RouteAlias(value = "", layout = ApplicationLayout.class)
    public class ProgressionView extends Div {
           public ProgressionView(@Autowired ScolProgressionPopulationRepository scolProgressionPopulationRepository) {
               var items = scolProgressionPopulationRepository.findAll();

               // I try this..
               Hibernate.initialize(items);
               // and this ...
               Hibernate.initialize(items.get(0));

               // this works:
               System.out.println("this is ok:" +items.size());

               // but not this:
               System.out.println("err, could not initialize proxy - no Session :" +items.get(0).getProgressions().size());
```

I try many thing to make lazy loading work, (adding @Transactional, Hibernate.initialize...)

But I always end up with this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'nc.unc.scolarite.lmd.progression.gui.ProgressionView': Bean
>   instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [nc.unc.scolarite.lmd.progression.gui.ProgressionView]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection of role:
>   nc.unc.scolarite.lmd.progression.entities.ScolProgressionPopulation.progressions,
>   could not initialize proxy - no Session

PS: I don't want to use EAGER fetch. I want to lazy load the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new method in your repository that uses `join fetch` to fetch the related entities, something like

```
@Query("SELECT spp FROM ScolProgressionPopulation spp JOIN FETCH spp.progressions")
public List<ScolProgressionPopulation> findAllWithProgressions();
```

Another way is to add the `@Transactional` annotation to a method in your repository (then it can't be an interface), it might also work on a method in your view. You probably need to call `initialize` for all progression collections, which is not very efficient as it may create many DB queries.

```
@Transactional
public List<ScrolProgressionPopulation> findAllWithProgressions() {
    val spps = findAll();
    for(ScrolProgressionPopulation spp: spps) {
        Hibernate.initialize(spp.getProgressions();
    }
    return spps;
}
```

**Edit:** If you don't want to initialize all items, you can do something like this

```
@Transactional
public void initializeProgressions(ScrolProgressionPopulation spp) {
    Hibernate.initialize(spp.getProgressions());
}
```

and call this on demand.

Comment: My 2 cents about scaling of both of the approaches here: the first solution can be scaled by using [Entity Graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph). It will make managing multiple lazy collections easy (and remove the need for the java dev to know how to write proper and efficient JOIN queries). For the second solution here, I would recommend implementing this in a service layer when scaling.